# How can i execute a certain function on each sheet of a xlsx file having more that 100 sheets in a parallel way?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask, dask-delayed

I have an `xlsx` file  `File.xlsx`, it has more than 100 sheets.

I need to perform a certain function `f()` on each sheet's data and finally return a list of each sheet's operated appended together.

I tried using pandas, reading each sheet's data one by one and then applying the function on it and appending in a list. Which is taking a lot of time. Need to the reduce the operation time.

How can I make the sheet wise execution in parallel? Can i use DASK aor anything else?

Note: need to jsonify each sheet's data so using `df.to_json()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make the sheet wise execution in parallel? Can i use DASK aor anything else?

This is a trivial usage of Dask:

```py
import dask
import pandas as pd

@dask.delayed
def get_sheet(filename, sheet_index=0):
    return pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_index)

@dask.delayed
def process(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Inputs
    ------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        A Pandas DataFrame. For this example, this DataFrame represents on sheet.

    Returns
    -------
    out : pd.DataFrame
        A new dataframe that makes some modifications on the original sheet.
    """
    out = df.copy()
    out["foo"] = "bar"
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the sheets of the Excel file (test.xlsx has two sheets)
    future_dfs = [get_sheet("test.xlsx", sheet_index=i) for i in [0, 1]]

    # Process the sheets
    processed_dfs = [process(df) for df in future_dfs]

    # Now that we've detailed the computation, start the computation.
    dfs = dask.compute(processed_dfs)
```

The function `process` should not modify the input DataFrame because functions should be pure and not modify the inputs. See the docstring of `dask.delayed` for more detail: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-api.html#dask.delayed.delayed